# I am getting error while running this python code. The error is "ElementNotInteractableException". Can any on help me out?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

I want to open student login from this website: https://exams.mlrinstitutions.ac.in/
open website-->click on 'Logins'-->click on 'Student Login'

This code is working fine up to the opening and clicking Logins. But when the code clicks on 'Student Login' it is encountering an error.

For HTML code please open the webpage and use inspect elements.

**CODE**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
driver.get("https://exams.mlrinstitutions.ac.in/")

first = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "lnkLogins"))
)
first.click()

first = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "lnkStudent"))
)
first.click()
```

**ERROR**

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55873/devtools/browser/0977ccf6-90ba-4f79-b746-e8ff53bd4035
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\dile2\OneDrive\Desktop\mini\sel.py", line 19, in <module>
    first.click()
  File "C:\Users\dile2\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\dile2\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
[13984:14080:0210/201137.350:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [20:11:37.349] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
  File "C:\Users\dile2\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\dile2\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `presence_of_element_located()` use `element_to_be_clickable()`

```
driver.get("https://exams.mlrinstitutions.ac.in/")

first = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "lnkLogins")))
first.click()

first = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "lnkStudent")))
first.click()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, KunduK. I spent around 10hours to solve this but you did it in second!!!  If you don't mind may I know what is the difference between them?

Comment: @dileepNaidu : `presence_of_element_located()` verifies element present in the DOM tree but not interactable. Once element is visible you can interact with the element and for  `element_to_be_clickable()` used.

Comment: Got it! Thank you @KunduK.